# Compute the integral $\int_C (z^2-1)^\frac{1}{2} dz$ where $R>1$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

Let C be the circle of Radius $R>1$, centered at the origin, in the complex plane. Compute the integral

$\int_C (z^2-1)^\frac{1}{2} dz$

where we employ a branch of the integrand defined by a straight branch cut connecting $z=1$ and $z=-1$, and $(z^2-1)^\frac{1}{2} > 0 $ on the line $y=0$, $x>1$. Note that the singularities are not isolated in this case. One way to do this integral is to expand the integrand in a Laurent series valid for $|{z}|> 1$ and integrate term by term

Answer (score 2):

Consider the contour $\Gamma$ below.

[image: dogbone]

This consists of two pieces: the circle $z=R$, $R \gt 1$, minus the dogbone inside the circle, consisting of two small circular arcs at $z=\pm 1$ of radius $\epsilon$, and joined by line segments above and below the real axis.

Now consider $f(z) = \sqrt{(z-1)(z+1)}$.  On the upper line segment, $\arg{(z+1)} = 0$ and $\arg{(z-1)} = \pi$.  On the lower line segment, $\arg{(z+1)} = 0$, but $\arg{(z-1)} = -\pi$.  Thus, the contour integral about $\Gamma$ is, in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$,

$$\oint_{\Gamma} dz \, \sqrt{z^2-1} = \int_{|z|=R} dz \, \sqrt{z^2-1} + i \int_1^{-1} dx \, \sqrt{1-x^2} - i \int_{-1}^1 dx \, \sqrt{1-x^2} $$

By Cauchy's theorem, the integral about $\Gamma$ is zero.  Thus,

$$ \int_{|z|=R} dz \, \sqrt{z^2-1}  = i 2 \int_{-1}^1 dx \, \sqrt{1-x^2} = i \pi$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R\ >\ 1}\,\,\,
\pars{z^{2} - 1}^{1/2}\,\,\dd z}\ =\
\overbrace{\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ R\ >\ 1}\,\,\root{z + 1}\root{z - 1}
\,\,\dd z}^{\substack{\ds{Both\ root\ are\ de\!fined\ as} \\[1mm]
\ds{Principal\ Branchs}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\int_{-R}^{-1}\root{-x - 1}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\root{-x + 1}\expo{\ic\pi/2}
\,\dd x
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{-1}^{1}\root{x + 1}\root{-x + 1}\expo{\ic\pi/2}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{1}^{-1}\root{x + 1}\root{-x + 1}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\,\dd x
\\[2mm] &\
-\int_{-1}^{-R}\root{-x - 1}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}\root{-x + 1}\expo{-\ic\pi/2}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
-2\ic\int_{-1}^{1}\root{1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x =
-4\ic\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos^{2}\pars{\theta}\,\dd\theta
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{-\pi\,\ic} \\ &
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

Hint: The value is independent of $R$ (by Cauchy's integral theorem). Let $R \to \infty$ and use the "residue at $\infty$" or compute the limit in another way (for example using that $(z^2-1)^{1/2} \approx z$ for $|z|$ large). You need to precise that estimate of course.

Comment: So would the integral just be zero via Cauchy Integral Theorem? Or is there some aspect of the question I'm not grasping.

Comment: No, you need a slightly better estimate as $R\to \infty$ (you need to take possible $1/z$ terms into account). A third option is to shrink the curve to the interval $[-1,1]$ and compute the resulting integral using calculus techniques.

Comment: Ok, so I have computed a Laurent series in the form $z - \frac{1}{2z} - \frac{1}{8z^3} - \frac{1}{16z^5} - \frac{5}{128z^7} + .... $ that converges for $R \rightarrow \infty$ and the by the Cauchy Integral Formula computed the integral to be $2 \pi i * (-1/2) = -\pi i$